# HTML5 Ajaxify - clashes with other simple jquery scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

So I'm trying to implement this on my website – https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify

Works fine on most pages, but there are two pages that rely on two simple scripts. The first one is

```
  jQuery(function() {

      var adjustArticleHeights = (function () {

        var leftColumnHeight = 0,
          rightColumnHeight = 0,
          $articles = jQuery('.shop-item');

        for (var i = 0; i < $articles.length; i++) {

          if (leftColumnHeight > rightColumnHeight) {
            rightColumnHeight += $articles.eq(i).addClass('right').outerHeight(true);
          } else {
            leftColumnHeight += $articles.eq(i).outerHeight(true);
          }
        }

        return $articles;
      })();
    });
```

But the weird thing is, if I'm on another page. Then go to this page, the script doesn't work. Then if I refresh the page, the script does work.

The second script below, it doesn't fire at all. No matter how many times I refresh

```
function() {
    jQuery('.image-caption').hide();
    jQuery('.image-hover ').hover( function() {
        jQuery(this).find('.image-caption').fadeIn(300);
    }, function() {
        jQuery(this).find('.image-caption').fadeOut(300);
    });
};
```

I also now get an error "`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`" on line 1.

Comment: `"The second script below, it doesn't fire at all."`  This is typically the case with an anonymous function that you never call! :)

Comment: Oh thanks, it works when I refresh it now!

Comment: Does this resolve the entirety of your question?

Comment: No, because I would like it work without having to refresh. It must be a problem with the ajaxify but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Just call it.

try

```
function() {
    jQuery('.image-caption').hide();
    jQuery('.image-hover ').hover( function() {
        jQuery(this).find('.image-caption').fadeIn(300);
    }, function() {
        jQuery(this).find('.image-caption').fadeOut(300);
    });
}();
```

note "()"